# How to serve static content in a Java web app from internal server?

Tags: java, http, web-applications, webserver, static-content

*It's a standard (possibly trivial) situation, but I cannot find detailed information on the topic.*

Suppose we have a web application **A** (`http://my-webapp`) and a file server **F** (`http://file-server`).

For clarity:

- **A** is run on Jetty 9;
- **F** is visible for Jetty server, and NOT visible for a client.

What is the best practice to show in **A** a picture stored on **F**?

Suppose client makes a request `http://my-webapp/pictures/123`, where `123` - any id, which somehow points to a picture stored as `http://file-server/storage/xxx123.jpg`, and expects to see the picture in the browser.

Comment: can't you download content of files that are in F from A server and pass it to client? you can think of your file server something like a database

Comment: you could have an .htaccess rule that redirects `http://my-webapp/pictures/{id}` to a script in A that reads the image file content from F and returns it

Comment: @Kaddath, path to a picture on the file server should be determined by business logic, which is written on Java, so static rules won't work here/

Comment: "F is visible for Jetty server, and NOT visible for a client." - visible how?

Comment: @nafas, actually it's a plan B, which has problems with cleaning content cached on A. I would prefer to find a way to create something like an InputStream, which starts on F and ends in a servlet of A, to prevent intermediate storing of data on A.

Comment: @Neville, webapp server and file server are in a local network, webapp server has access  to F, webapp server hosts A. A consumes request from anyone outside who has access to URL `http://my-webapp`

Comment: @diziaq what Kaddath describe might be pauseable. again, why would you cache data in A if you don't want them to be cached, I mean surely you can turn off caching in server A, no?

Comment: @nafas, probably, I mistreated the `download` word in your comment. Actually I'm looking for an example of Java code, implementing this "downloading bridge" between a client and the file server. I'd be perfect if you show what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose the following solution as a minimal example that could be a good starting point.

Redirection by `.htaccess` seems to be doing similar things on the low level.

Actually the problem is supposed to be solved by web application server itself without intervention of external tools (like Apache httpd or Nginx).

### 1. Declare servlet in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>pictures</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myapplication.servlets.HiddenFileServlet </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>pictures</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pictures/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

### 2. Implement the servlet

```
public class HiddenFileServlet extends HttpServlet
{     
  @Inject
  MyService myService; // a service for paths finding on http://file-server

  @Override
  protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws IOException
  {        
    String requestedUri = req.getRequestURI();

    String fileName = myService.getFileName( requestedUri );

    String mime = getServletContext().getMimeType( fileName );

    if ( mime == null )
    {
      resp.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR );
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      resp.setContentType( mime );
    }

    // path on http://file-server/storage
    URL fileFullPath = myService.getInternalPath( requestedUri );

    URL file = new URL( fileFullPath );

    try (
        InputStream in = file.openStream();
        OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream()
    )
    {
       org.apache.commons.compress.utils.IOUtils.copy( in, out );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Best practice" covers a *lot* of ground.

For load and performance reasons, it's a good idea to use a web server (like NGINX or Apache) rather than an application server to serve static assets. Most production environments have this set up, using a web server to proxy requests to the application server when necessary.

If you have such a setup, you could map the images drive on **F** as a drive on your web server, and use a .htaccess rewrite rule to deal with file name logic.

If that's not possible because the file name logic cannot be captured in a regex or similar, you could write a servlet on **A** to issue a redirect to a "regular" web location. Something along the lines of:

- client requests `http://my-webapp/pictures/123`
- servlet translates /pictures/123 to http://my-webapp/static_pictures/xxx123
- servlet issues 302 redirect to http://my-webapp/static_pictures/xxx123
- client follows redirect

I strongly recommend you do *not* use a servlet to read the file from **F** and then stream that to the browser; this consumes large amounts of memory on your application server, and may slow down or even fail depending on your local network conditions. Your application's performance will almost certainly deteriorate very quickly under load.